# Power Sets ~ Recursion ~ Hasse Diagrams

Tags: c++, recursion, binary

(SEE BELOW ALSO)

So I've got some functions and some operators for a set-manipulation program I'm coding, and I want to have power sets as a utility too (never mind the comments in the code). I don't want to use a binary approach, but I want to use recursion. I saw in Ralph Oberste-Vorth's book *Bridge to Abstract Mathematics* a definition of power sets (page 65), and on the next page I see all these equivalences like "if S = X, then P(S) = P(X)," and "if A and B are sets, then P(A) U P(B) = P(A U B)," and I'm reminded of recursion. I think recursion could work here but I'm not sure. I was playing around with Mathematica's Combinatorica package, and that one [Haverford College paper](http://www.haverford.edu/math/cgreene/posets/posets300-doc1.pdf) on Hasse Diagrams, and I thought I could work out, in much the same way as is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEaC1kgzIKo) four minutes in, some kind of method based on the corresponding diagram for some set of size n, but I don't know that that will lead me the right way. I would like to build off of my already-built functions/operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

set<int> SetUnion( set<int> A , set<int> B ) // tus koj hlub
{
    //A.insert( B.begin() , B.end() );
    //return A;

    set<int> pump;
    for( set<int>::iterator cycle = A.begin() ; cycle != A.end() ; ++cycle )
    {
        pump.insert(*cycle);
    }
    for( set<int>::iterator cycle = B.begin() ; cycle != B.end() ; ++cycle )
    {
        pump.insert(*cycle);
    }
    return pump;
}

set<int> SetIntersection( set<int> A , set<int> B ) // tus koj hlub
{
    set<int> pump;
    for( set<int>::iterator cycle = A.begin ; cycle != A.end() ; ++cycle )
    {
        if( B.find(*cycle) != B.end() )
        {
            pump.insert(*cycle);
        }
    }
    return pump;
}

set<int> SetDifference( set<int> A , set<int> B )
{
    set<int> pump;
    for( set<int>::iterator cycle = A.begin ; cycle != A.end() ; ++cycle )
    {
        if( B.find(*cycle) == B.end() )
        {
            pump.insert(*cycle);
        }
    }
    return pump;
}

set<int> SymmetricDifference( set<int> A , set<int> B )
{
    return SetUnion( SetDifference( A , B ) , SetDifference( B , A ) );
    //return SetDifference( SetUnion( A , B ) , SetIntersection( A , B ) );
}

set<set<int>> PowerSet( set<int> A )
{
    /*statements*/
}

set<int> Complement( set<int> A , int B )
{
    set<int> pump;
    for( int i = 1 ; i<=B ; i++ )
    {
        pump.insert(i);
    }
    set<int> collect = SetDifference( A , pump );
    return collect;
}

set<int> operator+(set<int> A , set<int> B)
{
    return SetUnion( A, B );
}
set<int> operator+(set<int> A , int B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(B);
    return SetUnion( A , C );
}
set<int> operator+(int A , set<int> B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(A);
    return SetUnion( B , C );
}
set<int> operator-(set<int> A , set<int> B)
{
    set<int> pump;
    for( set<int>::iterator cycle = A.begin ; cycle != A.end() ; ++cycle )
    {
        if( B.find(*cycle) == B.end() )
        {
            pump.insert(*cycle);
        }
    }
    return pump;
}
set<int> operator-(set<int> A , int B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(B);
    set<int> pump = SetDifference( A , C );
    return C;
}
set<int> operator-(int A , set<int> B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(A);
    set<int> pump = SetDifference( B , C );
    return pump;
}
set<int> operator^(set<int> A , set<int> B)
{
    return SetUnion( A , B );
}
set<int> operator^(set<int> A , int B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(B);
    set<int> pump = SetUnion( A , C );
    return pump;
}
set<int> operator^(int A , set<int> B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(A);
    set<int> pump = SetUnion( B , C );
    return pump;
}
set<int> operator%(set<int> A , set<int> B)
{
    return SymmetricDifference( A , B );
}
set<int> operator%(set<int> A , int B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(B);
    set<int> pump = SymmetricDifference( A , C );
    return pump;
}
set<int> operator%(int A , set<int> B)
{
    set<int> C;
    C.insert(A);
    set<int> pump = SymmetricDifference( B , C );
    return pump;
}
set<int> operator~(set<int> A)
{
    set<int> pump;
    vector<int> hose;
    for( set<int>::iterator cycle = A.begin() ; cycle != A.end() ; ++cycle )
    {
        hose.push_back(*cycle);
    }
    int last_value = 
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out , set<int>& B) // tus koj hlub
{
    int count=0;
    if( B.size() == 0 )
    {
        out << "{}";
        return out;
    }
    else
    {
        set<int>::iterator it;
        out << "{";
        for( it = B.begin() ; it != B.end() ; ++it )
        {
            ++count;
            if( count == B.size() )
            {
                out << *it;
            }
            else
            {
                out << *it << ", ";
            }
        }
        out << "}";
        return out;
    }
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in , set<int>& B) // tus koj hlub
{
    int user_input;
    while(1)
    {
        in>>user_input;
        if(user_input == -1)
            break;
        B.insert(user_input);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Also, why do I get an error on my "<<" operator symbol in the function here:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out , set<set<int>>& B)
{
    int count=0;
    if( B.size() == 0 )
    {
        out << "{}";
        return out;
    }
    else
    {
        set<set<int>>::iterator it;
        out << "{";
        for( it = B.begin() ; it != B.end() ; ++it )
        {
            count++;
            if( count == B.size() )
            {
                out << *it;
            }
            else
            {
                out << *it << ", ";
            }
        }
        out << "}";
        return out;
    }
}
```

---

The answer given by Mr. Shields produces the following error. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work:

> Error: class "std::_Tree_const_iterator, std::allocator>>>> "has no member "insert"

---

ANSWER FROM AUTHOR:

```
set<set<int>> PowerSet( const set<int> A )
{
    set<set<int>> ps;

    if( A.size() == 0 )
    {
        ps.insert( set<int>() );

        return ps;
    }

    set<int>::iterator it = A.begin();

    int n = *it;

    set<int> s1 = A;

    s1.erase( n );

    set<set<int>> ps1 = PowerSet( s1 );

    set<set<int>> ps2;

    for( set<set<int>>::iterator it = ps1.begin() ; it != ps1.end() ; ++it )
    {
        set<int> ss = *it;

        ss.insert( n );

        ps2.insert (ss );
    }

    for( set<set<int>>::iterator it = ps1.begin() ; it != ps1.end() ; ++it )
    {
        ps.insert(*it);
    }

    for( set<set<int>>::iterator it = ps2.begin() ; it != ps2.end() ; ++it )
    {
        ps.insert( *it );
    }

    return ps;
}
```

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, I'd like to see how it'd be done using binary.

Comment: All the code was written by me.

Comment: I think for the binary trick you'd have to let some `s` be such that `int s = B.size()`, and then I'd need to create 2^B.size() vectors, or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This C++ code below is *horribly* inefficient, but I think it should give you the idea for how to do this recursively. The recursion rule is basically this:

- `P({}) = {{}}`

  - the power set of the empty set is the set containing the empty set
- `P({n} U S) = { {n} U T | T in P(S) } U P(S)`

  - every set in the power set of `{n} U S` either contains `n` or does not contain `n` - exactly one of each for each set in the power set of `S`

Be aware that a set of cardinality `K` has a power set of cardinality `2^K`. So you don't want to perform this operation on any large sets!

---

```
set<set<int>> PowerSet( set<int> A )
{
    set<set<int>> PA;
    if (A.empty())
    {
        //case: P({}) = {{}}

        PA.insert(A);
    }
    else
    {
        //case: P({n} U S) = { {n} U T | T in P(S) } U P(S)

        int n = *A.begin();
        A.erase(A.begin());

        //A is now "S" from the explanation above this code

        auto PS = PowerSet(A);
        for (auto T = PS.begin(); T != PS.end(); ++T)
        {
            //add each set T from P(S)
            PA.insert(*T);

            //add each set T from P(S) with n included as well
            T->insert(n);
            PA.insert(*T);
        }
    }
    return PA;
}
```

Comment: Let me check. While I do, could you explain your mental process? If not, no biggy.

Comment: @TyquanPesik The mental process is taking the standard recursive definition of the power set from mathematics [(link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) and then translating that directly into code. :)

Comment: I see. My use of the expression "mental process" is not so welcomed.

Comment: I get an error though unfortunately. T->insert(n) get's an error message.

Comment: @TyquanPesik Did you get the code to work? It was just written in the browser, so I hadn't checked that it compiled or anything...

Comment: You didn't check that it compiled? Who does that? Always check! Anyway, see my answer. It actually works. I checked. :-)

Comment: If anybody'd like a copy of my program, then e-mail me.